# Bash- Parse a word if a symbol exists

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to parse a file into specific strings. I want to get a region from one section of a file but it can be variable. Here is the file format:

```
info info2 info3 num:num-num_1|SFSDFDSFAWEAB-SDSSDF|SDFSD207;DSFDS140  
info info2 info3 num:num-num|SFSDFDCDVD-SDDFSDFF|SDFSD207;DSFDS140  
info info2 info3 num:num-num_2|SFSDDSFD-ERSWSDFSDF|SDFSD207;DSFDS140
```

I am trying to get the `num:num-num_1` to just be `num:num-num` but not every entry has the "_#" so I have managed this much:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do 
titletmp=$(echo $line | cut -d'\t' -f4)
roi=$(echo $titletmp | cut -d'|' -f1)

done
```

Which gets me as far as: `num:num-num_1` but I can't figure out how to do the next bit. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the underline symbol and anything which follows, use suffix removal:

```
roi=${roi%_*}
```

For example:

```
$ roi=num:num-num_1
$ roi=${roi%_*}
$ echo $roi
num:num-num
```

Comment: That is much better than I was going for. I had a complex iteration through the string. Thanks